# Does Weblogic 12c server ignore http.proxy* parameters?

Tags: java, proxy, weblogic, weblogic12c

I'm running Weblogic 12.1.2 on Mac OS X and I have a system wide proxy set in Network Configuration.

I wan't Weblogic to ignore the proxy setting and use direct connection to web services. However, the Weblogic seems to ignore any command line `http.proxy*` parameters.

I modified startup script to add following parameters:

`-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=* -Dava.net.useSystemProxies=false -Dhttp.proxySet=false`

but Weblogic still tries to use proxy to connect to web service.

Anyone experiencing similar behavior? Should I use some specific prefix?

**EDIT:** Weblogic 12.1.1 seems to ignore proxy settings at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I forgot that I must re-set `http` **and** `https` proxy.

The best place to do it is in file `setDomainEnv.sh` by adding following lines to the bottom:

`PROXY_SETTINGS="-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=false -Dhttp.proxyHost=\"\" -Dhttps.proxyHost=\"\" -Dhttp.proxyPort=\"\" -Dhttps.proxyPort=\"\""
export PROXY_SETTINGS`

Answer (score 1):

you should set in http.nonProxyHosts

http.nonProxyHosts: a list of hosts that should be reached directly, bypassing the proxy. This is a list of patterns separated by '|'. The patterns may start or end with a '*' for wildcards. Any host matching one of these patterns will be reached through a direct connection instead of through a proxy.

```
java -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=”localhost|host.example.com” GetURL
```

Comment: Yes, this is how it should work. But I doesn't work under Weblogic 12c.